Simple image alignment tool for noisy images
Is there an tool to automatically align hand-held images so that I can stack them?
Old Sony compact camera I have could take multiple short exposures and stack them using onboard processor to reduce noise. Modern smartphones can do similar thing. I'm trying to reproduce this, but with any camera, just by taking multiple exposures.

I'm not looking for astro-photography. Photos will be of mostly non-moving subjects, but there might not be stars to use as reference for alignment.
I'm not looking for focus stacking.
Hugin's align_image_stack refuses to work. It can't find features in dark, noisy images.
Ideally I'm looking for software that works on Linux and has batch processing, but it's not an requirement.

There are lot's of tools, but the noise and lack of stars makes every single one I tried fail. I also don't need complicated process with dark-frames etc.
